# iOS: why object turns to the start position after animation comletion

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiviewanimation

)) I'm trying to animate UIButton (two parallel animations: changing of images and moving) as follows, after animation button should be moved, but after completing animation button turns to the start position. Please help to fix it! Thanks in advance!

```
- (IBAction)bugOneTapped:(id)sender
{
   [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                 animations:^{
                     self.bugOneButton.imageView.animationImages =
                     [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bugOne3"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"bugOne2"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"bugOne1"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"bugOne2"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"bugOne3"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"bugOne4"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"bugOne5"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"bugOne4"],nil];
                     self.bugOneButton.imageView.animationDuration = 0.3;
                     [self.bugOneButton.imageView startAnimating];


                     self.bugOneButton.center = CGPointMake(self.bugOnePositionX, self.bugOneButton.center.y - 50);
                     self.bugOnePositionY = self.bugOnePositionY - 50;


                 }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     [self.bugOneButton.imageView stopAnimating];
                 }];

self.bugOneButton.center = CGPointMake(self.bugOnePositionX, self.bugOnePositionY);  
}
```

Comment: You are again setting the center again to the initial position after the completion block..

Comment: remove this self.bugOnePositionY = self.bugOnePositionY - 50;

Comment: Thanks, but i have changed Y-position above, why it didn't changed?

Answer (score 0):

Remove below line in your code

```
self.bugOneButton.center = CGPointMake(self.bugOnePositionX, self.bugOnePositionY);
```

It will fix..

Answer (score 0):

@Genie Wanted said is right，remove code

```
self.bugOneButton.center = CGPointMake(self.bugOnePositionX, self.bugOnePositionY)
```

this will reset the button position！

Comment: I think you used the third party library,then the animation time is longer than your animation's time,so when it finished, will reset it。Or method stopAnimating caused

Answer (score 0):

remove this two line

```
- (IBAction)bugOneTapped:(id)sender
{
   [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                 animations:^{
                     self.bugOneButton.imageView.animationImages =
                     [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bugOne3"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"bugOne2"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"bugOne1"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"bugOne2"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"bugOne3"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"bugOne4"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"bugOne5"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"bugOne4"],nil];
                     self.bugOneButton.imageView.animationDuration = 0.3;
                     [self.bugOneButton.imageView startAnimating];

                     self.bugOneButton.center = CGPointMake(self.bugOnePositionX, self.bugOneButton.center.y - 50);

                 }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     [self.bugOneButton.imageView stopAnimating];
                 }];


}
```

Comment: And perhaps, startAnimating and stopAnimating aren't necessary here when you use AnimationBlocks

Comment: i think he is using any third party library for making animation @GenieWanted